# jQuery, slide toggle only works for 1 section

Tags: jquery, html, css, slidetoggle

First post here, go easy on me :)

I'm new to web development and this is my first project. I think i'm ok on the HTML and CSS side of things and I have now started using jQuery.
jQuery is what I'm struggling on.

I have this in the head section of my intranet page:

**JQUERY**

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("#flip").click(function(){
    $("#panel").slideToggle("fast");
  });
});
```

and I have this:

**HTML**

```
    <div class="announcements">
        <div id="flip">
            <h2 class="announcements">title here</h2>
            <div class="announcesig">
                Informed by: name here<br>Date: date here
            </div>
        </div>
        <div id="panel">
            <p>comment here<br>
            more comment
            <a target="_blank" href="link here">Click Here</a></p>
        </div>
    </div>
```

This works as intended but if I do it for another `<div class="Announcements">` the same format as above it doesn't work for the next but still works for the first.

**Question**

Do I have to do a script for each announcement e.g. `#flip1`, `#flip2` then do the CSS and HTML for each one? Or is there an easier way?

I'm sorry if this isn't clear enough.

Comment: Make sure your IDs are unique.

Comment: Make sure you use classes instead of ids. Where ids should be unique and classes can be used in multiple places. :)

Comment: can you show me your whole code here

Comment: [like this?](http://jsfiddle.net/zpwy2kkn/)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use a class instead. Like mentioned in your comments, Ids should be unique, classes however can be used multiple times. When you change the id's to classes you can use the following:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $(".panel").hide();
  $(".flip").click(function(){
    $(this).next().slideToggle("fast");
  });
});
```

Here is a working example:

http://jsfiddle.net/RubenJonker/ygmj3wts/

Comment: late edit: $(".panel").hide(); was needed. Ruben had this in his link

Comment: Did that to demonstrate, but didn't saw it in your example. I'll update it in this post.

Comment: The weird thing is I didn't have the hide in my original code, yet the announcements were up if I ran it in IE

Answer (score 1):

**Use This Code**

```
<div class="announcements">
        <div class="flip">
            <h2 class="announcements">title here</h2>
            <div class="announcesig">
                Informed by: name here<br>Date: date here
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="panel">
            <p>comment here<br>
            more comment
            <a target="_blank" href="link here">Click Here</a></p>
        </div>
    </div>
```

- JQuery Function

`

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $(".flip").click(function(){
    $(this).siblings(".panel").slideToggle("fast");
  });
});
```

`

Comment: This also Works, what's the difference between .siblings from prog and .next from Ruben?

Comment: I first added the siblings and later changed it to next, so he took my code;) but siblings is the nodes on the same level. So siblings(".panel") gives the nodes on the same level with the class panel.

Answer (score 0):

Please try this

```
<div class="announcements">
        <!--Panel 1-->
        <div class="flip">
            <div>
                <h2 class="announcements">title here</h2>
                <div class="announcesig">
                    Informed by: name here<br>Date: date here
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="slide" style="display: none">
                <p>comment here<br>
                more comment
                <a target="_blank" href="link here">Click Here</a></p>
            </div>
        </div>

        <!--Panel 2-->
        <div class="flip">
            <div>
                <h2 class="announcements">title here</h2>
                <div class="announcesig">
                    Informed by: name here<br>Date: date here
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="slide" style="display: none">
                <p>comment here<br>
                more comment
                <a target="_blank" href="link here">Click Here</a></p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

and the jquery is

```
$(function() {
            $(".flip").click(function(){
                $('.slide').hide();
                $(this).find('.slide').slideToggle("fast");
            });
        })
```